# Automatic e-mail/text message when a calculation has finished?

Tags: programming, automation, email

Sometimes *Mathematica* takes quite a while to finish calculations and it would be convenient to be able to move away from the computer while it is working. I was wondering if there is any "clever" hack that can be used purely within *Mathematica* to e-mail updates on the computation.

I can think of a very rough way of getting an update other than actually accessing the machine, which would be by exporting some output to a file in Dropbox. From another machine connected to Dropbox I could see when the file is updated. But this seems to me like a very ugly solution.

A less ugly solution would be to write an external script, probably with python, and then have *Mathematica* run it at some point in the calculation. This would allow for both e-mail and text message updates (using Skype or a similar service and the appropiate python modules).

Is there any way to do something similar purely within *Mathematica*?

Comment: `SendMail` is the API supported by M but you need to find one open SMTP server to send your mail. Internet is full of these, if you know how to find.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/customize-front-end-to-add-notifications-when-evaluation-finishes)

Comment: There are services with which you can easily send text messages. They use REST APIs so you can interact with them using for example `URLFetch`.

Comment: An even better idea is if these computations take awhile schedule them for when you are drinking beer :) So don;t even bother starting them and *then* moving away from computer. Combine `ScheduleTask` and friends with some of the email solutions you get below. For scheduling when Mathematica is not already running here is an example (that can also be combined with email): http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7590/. So you are out having a beer and u get a message saying computation done. Maybe even an attachment of a plot.

Answer (score 56):

I like to use the docked cells for this purpose. I create two buttons in my "heavy processing" notebooks:

[image]

- the first is a bell that rings thrice when the computation is finished — used to alert me when I'm at my computer, but doing something else.
- the second is to send an email to myself when the processing is finished – used when I'm away from my computer, but online (on iPad or a different machine)

Both of them are `Button`s with a queued evaluation, so as to prevent the front end from evaluating it pre-emptively (i.e., it will evaluate only after the processing is finished).

You use these buttons by first evaluating (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) all the cells that you want processed and then click the desired button and walk away.

The code for this is below:

```
With[{
    bell = Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Bell_alt_font_awesome.svg/200px-Bell_alt_font_awesome.svg.png"], 
    email = Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Aiga_mail.svg/200px-Aiga_mail.svg.png"], 
    ir = ImageResize[#, {16, 16}] &},

    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
        DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Row[{
            Button[ir@bell, 
               Do[EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[]]]; Pause[0.5], {3}], 
               Method -> "Queued", Appearance -> "Palette"],
            Spacer@5,
            Button[ir@email, 
                SendMail[
                    "From" -> "me@domain.com", 
                    "To" -> "myself@domain.com", 
                    "Subject" -> "Finished processing!", "Body" -> "", 
                    "Server" -> "mail.domain.com"
                ], 
                Method -> "Queued", Appearance -> "Palette"]
        }]]
    ]
 ]
```

Use additional options to `SendMail` as necessary, depending on your email provider.

Comment: Could also set `$Post` to get feedback at every output as in `$Post = (Do[EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[]]]; Pause[0.5], {3}]; #) &;`

Comment: I can't believe you missed hitting 200 "yesterday" with an answer like this. +1 for today.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :)

Comment: Neat answer, recently linked. +1

Comment: Can somebody explain me what is to be done with the code above in order to have this work?

Comment: @Olórin Can you explain what is confusing about it or what doesn't work for you?

Comment: @R.M. if I have some input process, how do I use the code above so that a bell will ring when it is done?

Comment: @Olórin That is addressed in the answer... please read it fully. I quote: _"You use these buttons by first evaluating (Shift-Enter) all the cells that you want processed and then click the desired button and walk away."_

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the bell button in such a way that it open up a dialog box which shows up even if I am doing something else on my laptop? Maybe even in a different screen (using windows)

Answer (score 23):

As stated in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/configuring-mathematica-to-send-email-from-a-notebook) answer you can do the following to send an email form *Mathematica*.  Because of the nature of how email servers are set up you will have to have some server that sends the email.

```
SendMail[
 "To" -> "YYY...@me.com",
 "Subject" -> "Example Message",
 "Body" -> "My text",
 "From" -> "xxx...@gmail.com",
 "Server" -> "smtp.gmail.com",
 "UserName" -> "xxx...@gmail.com",
 "Password" -> Automatic,
 "PortNumber" -> 587,
 "EncryptionProtocol" -> "StartTLS"
 ]
```

Depending on what type of service you are on you should be able to send text messages through your email by appending @emailprovider.com

For example:

```
US Cellular: email.uscc.net
Verizon: vtext.com
Virgin: vmobl.com
AT&T: txt.att.net
Nextel: messaging.nextel.com
Sprint: messaging.sprintpcs.com
T-Mobile: tmomail.net
```

Read more: [How to Send a Text Message from Email](http://www.ehow.com/how_5060074_send-text-message-email.html#ixzz2bV3yHLKb)

Answer (score 16):

[Reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SendingEmail.html)

If you want results emailed then why not combine that with scheduling of the job? So in other words if you have computations that take awhile or you run regularly why hang around or why even be there to get them started?

More efficient use of time is to schedule the job and go and do something else. Have the job run while you are sleeping and get the results emailed and check on your phone when you wake up.

Create a `*.m` file containing code like this:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
Export["result plot.png", p1];
SendMail["From" -> "i.newton@gravity.com", 
  "To" -> "w.heisenberg@uncertainty.com", "ReplyTo" -> "", 
  "Subject" -> "How is the beer?", 
  "Body" -> "Here are the results of your scheduled task", 
  "Password" -> "xxxxx", "EncryptionProtocol" -> "SSL", 
  "PortNumber" -> 465, "Server" -> "smtp.gravity.com", 
  "Attachments" -> {"result plot.png"}];
```

and call it `task.m` and then run this file at a scheduled time (i.e. some time after beer o'clock)

```
RunScheduledTask[<< "task.m", {1}, AbsoluteTime[{2013, 8, 10, 17, 27, 0}]]
```

`ScheduledTask` and co requires Mathematica to be running but you can also use your systems scheduler to switch Mathematica on and off. [Here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7590) is how to do it on Macs as of about 3.5 years ago (it may need updating)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a text message on your cellphone when the calculation is done, you need a little bit more structure than what *Mathematica* has built in, but it's not too hard to do.

I use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) - "if this, then that", pronounced ift as in 'gift'. It's a free service which can do all sorts of things, to turn one sort of 'trigger' into an action on some other channel. It's quite easy to make a 'recipe' like this:

[image]

Arrange for *Mathematica* to send an email (using one of the multiple fine answers in this thread) to trigger@ifttt.com that contains the hashtag text "#Mathematica" in the subject line. (Make sure the `"From"` in your `SendMail` agrees with what you declare to ifttt, too.) You can then arrange for ifttt to send a text message to your phone with a bunch of information pulled from the email:

[image]

To be honest I haven't used this in a while but I have a feeling I'll be using it again soon enough. Full disclaimer: I am not in any way associated with ifttt - I just find it useful. I'm pretty sure there are other ways of sending SMS through online APIs that can be accessed either directly or through e.g. Python scripts, but this one is fairly simple.