# How to make the Mathematica icon flash in the taskbar?

Tags: interface

I have a somewhat long computation running in the background. I would like the Mathematica icon on the taskbar to flash once the computation is done. For example, Microsoft Outlook reminders make the taskbar flash:

[image]

How can I achieve the same effect in Mathematica? Is there a Mathematica command that makes the Mathematica icon in the taskbar flash?

**What I've tried:** `Beep[]` can be useful, but if you leave the computer for a while, you can miss the beep. The advantage of flashing is that it remains flashing indefinitely. Another alternative is `MessageDialog[]`, but you have no way of knowing that a message is up if Mathematica is minimized. It would be useful if `MessageDialog[]` produced the flashing in the taskbar, but that doesn't happen.

**Update:** Opening a `SystemDialogInput` is a hammer type of solution, although it gets the job done. I am reopening this question in case someone else comes up with something more subtle. The goal is to have some sort of alert that doesn't stop (like a beep would), so that if I leave the computer, when I return I could instantly see if the computation is done.

By the way, I am on Linux Mint, in case someone wants to get really low level :)

Comment: I don't think there are some commands that make the icon flash, but I usually add `Beep[]` at the end of code if it will take long time to compute.

Comment: @mm.Jang The problem with `Beep[]` is that if you leave the computer for a while and return, and you can miss the beep. The icon flashing remains flashing indefinitely.

Comment: This is OS dependent and not specific to _Mathematica_. You might have better luck on [su]. If you're trying to set up a notification when the computation is finished, then you can perhaps use my answer here: [Automatic e-mail/text message when a calculation has finished?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30169)

Comment: @rm-rf It may be OS dependent. But it is specific to Mathematica. I want a *Mathematica* command (similar to `Beep[]`) that makes the taskbar flash.

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X and if *Mathematica* is hidden then using `SystemDialogInput["FileSave"]` makes the Dock icon bounce.  Perhaps under Windows it will flash the Taskbar icon?

Comment: @becko http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/05/12/8490184.aspx

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar `SystemDialogInput["FileSave"]` makes the taskbar icon flash. But it also brings up a File Save dialog that can be confusing. I guess I can use it temporarily. But it would be nice if there was a command that made the taskbar flash without side effects.

Comment: @becko What rm-rf meant (I believe) is that since Mathematica does not contain built-in functionality for this, the question would be the very same for any other software: how do you make the taskbar button of a particular program flash?  Not meaning to say that this should be closed here (it would be very useful to have what you're asking for), but you are indeed more likely to get an answer on superuser.com.

Comment: You can do this with AutoHotKey (or equivalent). Cross-platform, free, check their site and fora, many examples there.

Answer (score 9):

This is perhaps not a completely satisfactory solution but it is *Mathematica* based.

Unlike `MessageDialog[]`

```
SystemDialogInput["FileSave"]
```

will make the Taskbar icon flash in Windows and the Dock icon bounce in Mac OS X under certain conditions.  (I believe the document must be minimised in Windows or hidden in Mac.)

Of course it has the slight side-effect of bringing up a file selection dialog but this could be used to ensure that the results of your long computations are saved to a file, e.g.

```
result = MyLongComputation[];
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", WindowTitle -> "Computation Complete"], result]
```

Using the `WindowTitle` option should also make the sudden appearance of the dialog box less likely to be confusing.

Comment: +1 Good idea. Converting the file selection dialog into something useful makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by upgrading to Mathematica 11 :)

Comment: The requested behavior is built into v11 on Windows.  So depending on your point of view, it does actually answer the question.

Comment: How exactly? I have Mathematica 11. Note that I am on Linux Mint. Are you saying that in Windows, `MessageDialog` flashes the taskbar? Please expand.

Comment: @becko Just evaluate Pause[10] and task switch to some other app.  The icon should flash after roughly 10 seconds.

Comment: @becko This behavior does not exist on Linux in v11.  I can forward that on if you are interested...

Comment: The behavior does exist in v11 on Linux, but for me it keeps bugging, such that I will see it blinking on all my workspaces, until I close the notebook. Thus I am looking for ways of removing this setting.