# Receiving visual notifications even when Mathematica is minimized?

Tags: customization, interface, interactive

How to receive visual notifications on screen during long computation even when Mathematica is minimized?
Question is similar to this: [How to make the Mathematica icon flash in the taskbar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40423/how-to-make-the-mathematica-icon-flash-in-the-taskbar).

`MessageDialog[]` (or anything similar) would be great but I don't know how to force it to appear on screen when Mathematica is minimized.
Solution would be if with some command Mathematica could be automaticaly maximized but I couldn't find how to do it neither.

**Alternatives:** `Beep[]` is not an option for me because I keep sound turned off, besides I could easily miss the beep when I leave computer for a moment.
`SendMail[]` overall is an option. In fact, it works very well for me when I'm not at home. But when I'm sitting at my computer I want to receive instant message on screen.

I'm using Mathematica 9 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Actually [`MessageDialog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageDialog.html)does appear even if *Mathematica* is minimized.

Other MS Windows only solutions:

```
Alert[S_String] := Module[
  {filename = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "MmaAlert.vbs"}]},
  Export[
   filename,
    StringJoin["msgbox \"", S, "\", 0, \"Message from Mathematica\""],
    "String"];
  SystemOpen[filename];
  ]

Alert["Time for tea"]
```

or simply

```
Alert2[S_String] := Run["cmd /C msg * " <> S]
```