# A command to mark the end of a time consumming computation?

Tags: programming

This is nearly the same question as Automatic e-mail/text message when a calculation has finished?  but I need also the prompt on my computer --- I have not internet on my phone.

Can we ask mathematica either to sing or to print a message when a command known to be time consumming deliver its output ?

Comment: Look up `$Pre`/`$PrePrint`, and maybe `Beep[]`.

Comment: `Procedure[] \n Beep[]`? Related: [Automatic e-mail/text message when a calculation has finished?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30167/5478)

Comment: `Speak["The task is finished, master."]`.

Comment: All your suggestions are very nice but are inside mathematica --- up top the email. I was thinking od a message whcih would prompt a small windows in the middle of my screen