# E-mail and password

Tags: email

I've just learned Mathematica can send e-mails using external servers: this is great... ! Now, using this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/configuring-mathematica-to-send-email-from-a-notebook), I've set this up using my Gmail account. But is it possible to incorporate somewhere my Gmail password, so as not to have to add it every time in the

```
SendMail[..., "Password"-> ... ]
```

command? Thanks all for your help!

Comment: see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30836/encrypt-the-password-used-for-sendmail?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the link, this was precisely what I was looking for!