# I did not receive mail sent using Mathematica

Tags: mathematica-online, networking, email

I try to send mail using *Mathematica* to my Gmail account using [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/configuring-mathematica-to-send-email-from-a-notebook) and it works correctly.

The mail was sent correctly and I got this message:

```
 {"MessageID" -> "15416335454959396639.4.WolframLanguage.xxxxxxx@gmail.com"}
```

However, even though I can see the message in my Sent list, but I did not receive the mail, even after a long time! What is the problem?

Comment: So you sent an email using *Mathematica* from a Gmail address to a Gmail address, and it showed up as "sent" in the Gmail interface but it wasn't received? Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: maybe just that nonsense where gmail doesn't show mail sent to yourself in the inbox. Try sending to another account.

Comment: i send it to another account @yahoo.fr but it is not shown in inbox!